# Координаты курсора javascript

Tags: javascript

Как постоянно получать координаты курсора по `X` и `Y` с помощью Javascript?

Comment: А когда получать? Где? При каком событии? Вопрос очень размыт....

Answer (score 4):

```js
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
    console.log(mouseX + ' x ' + mouseY);
}
```

Comment: Можно переменные mouseX и mouseY как-то оттуда вынести?

Comment: @Goreh да. вынести куда именно?

Comment: Ну, чтобы использовать их где-то еще, например в функциях и т.д

Comment: Все, уже не надо